# mvc3 get form data from view in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

MVC3, View I have a label

```
 <label id="test"></label>
```

and in jquery I set the value on .blur. All works but when I click the submit button to go to the controller and I want to get the data that was displayed in the label, and it shows null.

the way I am retrieving the data is by using FormCollection class
e.g.

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
collection["test"]
```

what am I missing? 
thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Labels do not get submitted with a form post.

If you're updating the value of the label, you might want to also include a hidden input and store the same value there as well. Then access the input in the FormCollection.